# ionic/typescript function for save image to folder

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, ionic-framework, input

through the input type file I would like to save the chosen image in a folder. how can I do?

html code:

```
<ion-item >
      <ion-label>Immagine</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="file">Chose image</ion-input>
      <button ion-button color:"secondary" (click)="getImage()">Get Image</button>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do File plugin to write a file. Here is the complete example.

Install File Plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

app.module.ts file

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
@NgModule({
     providers: [   
        File
     ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML File

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item (click)="onImageClick()">
           <div>
               <ion-icon ios="ios-add-circle" md="md-add-circle"></ion-icon>
                  Add Files
           </div>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
           <button ion-button (click)="addImage()">Upload</button>
       </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

Typescript File

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

private Attachments: any[] = [];

constructor(private camera: Camera, private file:File) { }

public onImageClick() {

    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*'); //you can change also file type as **'file/*'**
    input.setAttribute("multiple", ""); // If you dont want multiple select file pls remove this line

    input.addEventListener('change', (event: any) => {      
      let fileList: File[] = event.target.files;
      console.log("File List Object Value",fileList);

        for (let fileIdx = 0; fileIdx < fileList.length; fileIdx++) {
                    let file = fileList[fileIdx];
                    this.attachmentBase64(file, fileIdx);
        }
         console.log("Attachments",this.Attachments);
    });

    input.click();
  }

private attachmentBase64(file: File, fileIndex: number) {
       let self=this;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
        }
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            //Read complete
            if (reader.readyState == 2) {
                self.Attachments[fileIndex].Base64 = reader.result;                
            }
        };
    }

   private addImage(){
      for(let file of this.Attachments){
         this.writeFile(file.Base64,"My Picture","FileName.png");
      }
  }


//here is the method is used to write a file in storage
public writeFile(base64Data: any, folderName: string, fileName: any) {
        let contentType = this.getContentType (base64Data);
        let DataBlob = this. base64toBlob(content, contentType);


// here iam mentioned this line this.file.externalRootDirectory is a native pre-defined file path storage. You can change a file path whatever pre-defined method.
        let filePath= this.file.externalRootDirectory + folderName;

         this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, DataBlob, contentType)
            .then((success) => {
                console.log("File Writed Successfully", success);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error Occured While Writing File", err);
            })
    }

//here is the method is used to get content type of an bas64 data
public getContentType(base64Data: any) {
        let block = base64Data.split(";");
        let contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];       
       return contentType;      
    }

//here is the method is used to convert base64 data to blob data
public base64toBlob(b64Data, contentType) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = 512;
        let  byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        let byteArrays = [];
        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }
        let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
        return blob;
    }
```

Working example. For any errors, please let me know.

References:

- File writing:
  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/
- Where to store a file:
  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files